# Existing Website Management & Content Modification without CMS

Tags: php, backend, administration

My client needs function for editing and updating the website content (text, image etc) with ease. Not with FTP or other thing but rather just page from where he can edit easily..

I found some website which provide this service a year back. The procedure was simple

1) Click the Admin button and enter credentials
2) Now in place editing feature is enabled.

I know there are javascript for inplace editing but i do not need that..
I want a MODERATOR page from where i will (admin) set which content he is allowed to modify.
I tried using
**PHPMYEDIT** 
and was happy but the program is too old fashioned there are many thing which are not updated..
Just like the PHPMYEDIT i need a Program OR a service online which have a feature of 
Existing website content editing / update / delete / modify
My website is in PHP / MYSQL / JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY and other addons.
Kindly suggest a solution to my problem.

recently i came up with a site
**http://grabaperch.com/**
that does exactly what i say but it is little complex (for the client) still suggest any thing like that. Suggestion are welcome..

Important - The pages/content are static

Answer (score 1):

I've used a service called CushyCMS before, with varying degrees of success. It does require that you add a class to the HTML selectors that you wish the client to be able to edit.

It is a type of 'lite' CMS without really being a CMS (it just hides the FTP transactions in the background and gives a simple WYSIWYG interface.

Hope that helps

Comment: will cushyCMS allow existing page integration. I also have several Jquery and the template is used for the website. There are many codes which I fear will be a setback while integration.

Comment: If you have a <div> in your existing site, and you want your client to be able to edit the contents, all you do is <div class="cushycms"> - and that's it. So yes, it can integrate into existing pages easily.

Comment: yeah i read abt it it seems a good solution but the problem is i want client to edit the site from phone (android / ios) pagelime seems to provide this service but when i checked it was not working. Any other cms which will give control via Android/iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert the website into wordpress it will be the best solution

Comment: it will be a lot of headache if i convert it to wordpress. First i do not know about wordpress and shifting entire site on that platform will cause severe javascript, jquery errors...

Answer (score 0):

If grabaperch.com is little complex for you,
take a look on Uzuvi, https://getuzuvi.com

This very little CMS also, like Perch, can be a drop-in editor of existing website.
But Uzuvi console UI has ultra simple design.

Need to say this CMS has no moderator feature you mentioned, may be yet.